# Javascript for conditional formatting stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, var, conditional-formatting

I'm using some code in create functional formatting. I'm a huge noob when it comes to code but I've tried to be logical about it and learn from others as well as through online tutorials.

I've been working on the code below which reads the RISK column in table and should loop through the IF statements.

```
<div id="[@field:Risk]"></div>

<script>
    var line_id = '[@field:Risk]';
    var line=document.getElementById(line_id).parentNode.parentNode;
    var elems = line.getElementsByTagName("td"); 

    for (var i = 0, m = elems.length; i < m; i++) {
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "Low") { elems[i].style.color="ForestGreen";} 
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "Low") { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "Mid") { elems[i].style.color="DarkOrange";}
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "Mid") { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "High") { elems[i].style.color = "Red";}
        if (elems[i].innerHTML == "High") { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";} 
    }
</script>
```

However after it finds the first instance of Low, Mid and High none of the other appearances of those terms is highlighted as per the formatting above. Effectively the loop stops after finding the three defined terms. I am puzzled as to why this may be the case. Can anyone help/explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more code context...

Comment: what does **elems** look like and how long is it?

Comment: I would start by throwing `console.log(elems[i].innerHTML)` in your loop and see if your assumption that the loop is stopping is actually correct.

Comment: Btw, You don't need `LANGUAGE="JavaScript`

Comment: Script take require `type= text/javascript` for javascript. But it's the default value, so not required anymore

Comment: I'm using the code in a HTML block in an application on Caspio Bridge, an online database/cloud platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, **see demo:** http://jsbin.com/capatoyidu/edit?html,console,output

However, your code could be reduced to the following:

```
<div id="[@field:Risk]"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var line_id='[@field:Risk]';
var line=document.getElementById(line_id).parentNode.parentNode;
var elems = line.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i=0, m=elems.length; i<m; i++) 
{
if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Low")  { 
  elems[i].style.color="ForestGreen";
  elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";
} else if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Mid") { 
  elems[i].style.color="DarkOrange";            
  elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";
} else if (elems[i].innerHTML=="High")  { 
  elems[i].style.color="Red";
  elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";
} 
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I've refreshed the application  I was making and this works but stops after the first 3 instances. Thanks!

Comment: you need to provide the complete html output for your <td> tags so we could see what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean the full html code for the page?

Comment: Yes, and if the page is generated dynamically, show the output of your html after your page is generated, the part of the code you included here is fine so far.

Comment: I'm unable to access that link, would you update your question with the complete html code? or use something like jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com and share the link?

Comment: The code is too big for this box and I think because I'm technically using a third-party interface (Caspio Bridge) the HTML code shows the token for the app etc instead of the code in action

Comment: Try using FireBug or Chrome Developer Tool to inspect the elements and copy the html code.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I got it working. I needed to create a dynamic HTML block within the app, place it within the footer placeholder of the report page and then place the code inside of that to make it work. I also had to disabled "AJAX" to for the code to be active. Thanks for your help cleaning up the code and all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that ?

```
<div id="[@field:Risk]"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var line_id='[@field:Risk]';
var line=document.getElementById(line_id).parentNode.parentNode;
var elems = line.getElementsByTagName("td");
var colors = {
  Low: "ForestGreen",
  Mid: "DarkOrange",
  High: "Red",
}

for (var i=0, m=elems.length; i<m; i++) {
  if (colors[elems[i].innerHTML]) {
    elems[i].style.fontWeight = 600;
    elems[i].style.color = colors[elems[i].innerHTML]
  } else {
    console.warn("Unknow value of " + elems[i].innerHTML + " for index " + i)
  }
}</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work at all, doesn't find the first instance.

Comment: OUps my bad, is better now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="[@field:Risk]"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">//use lowercase; LANGUAGE="JavaScript" is deprecated
var line_id='[@field:Risk]';
var line=document.getElementById(line_id).parentNode.parentNode;
var elems = line.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i=0, m=elems.length; i<m; i++) {
if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Low")  { 
    elems[i].style.color="ForestGreen";
    elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";} 
//if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Low") { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Mid")  { 
    elems[i].style.color="DarkOrange";
    elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
//if (elems[i].innerHTML=="Mid")  { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
if (elems[i].innerHTML=="High")  { 
    elems[i].style.color="Red";
    elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";}
//if (elems[i].innerHTML=="High")  { elems[i].style.fontWeight = "600";} 
}
</script>
```